# Javascript Code not running in Wordpress Pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress, highcharts, custom-wordpress-pages

EDIT here is the error from the console https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbR1q.jpg

I want to run a bit of code in a Wordpress Pages which works in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/w9ta5x2e/. 
I am just putting my code in the editor and I don't see anything. However the script will run if its something simple like: courtesy of https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_inner_html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"'>Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to create a .js file, it's a university setup wordpress site so I doubt I have much control with the root.

I can't make files on my Wordpress website, it is managed by a university and it doesn't allow me to

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(function() {
$.getJSON(
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/usdeur.json',
    function (data) {

        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: data
            }]
        });
    }
);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try to change  `$.getJSON` by `jQuery.getJSON`.

Comment: This did not make it run.

Comment: You can also use jQuery.noConflict()l And then use `jQuery` variable instead of `$` for jQuery related things. So `jQUery` will have the reference of jQuery and `$` will have the reference of other libraries which wordpress might be using. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @AbdulMannan that is almost always already implemented in wordpress installations

Comment: you have too many JS errors that might influence others. First fix all your syntax errors from top, disable all other scripts, then change all `$` to explicit `jQuery` calls. Also it would be better to load the script in footer

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Yes, agreed. But installing different plugins sometimes cause this to happen as well.

Comment: @AbdulMannan That is my point - you need to debug one thing at a time. one plugin after another and not all at once

Comment: You have used `highcharts` label yet this issue is not strictly related to it.

Comment: I didn't know if the issue was or was not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress usually runs jQuery in noConflict mode making `$` undefined

Try changing

```
 jQuery(function() {// $ undefined here
```

To

```
jQuery(function($) { // $ is jQuery here
```

Comment: This did not fix it.

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Is this code running after jQuery.js loads? Can't use jQuery object until the library itself loads

Comment: I'm a little confused because there are tons of errors https://imgur.com/a/OvP9cRr

Comment: Seems like there are a lot of jQuery issues. Why would it work in jsFiddle but not here?

Comment: I removed <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>   but for some reason <p> was inserted and threw an error
 https://imgur.com/a/RtMRoLD

Comment: Was a blank space in the pages code! I deleted all the blank lines and added @charlietfl 's code and that fixed it